# NodeJs API login B2C without B2C login page

Tags: javascript, node.js

All right?
I am in need of help with Azure AD B2C implementation. I need an API that manages the login for my application and that makes a connection with AAD B2C. However, I only find login options through the B2C login page. I would like to know if there is any way to implement in Node a form of login in my application without having to use the MS login screen. User entering with password and email and validating in AD. I saw that there is ROPC, but at the same time saying that it is an insecure method.

I am currently implementing it with ms graph, azure-graph, ms-rest-azure, but I think this way is wrong.
User enter the email prefix and password via post.

```
server.post('/login', (request, response) => {
  const {email, password} = request.body
  msRestAzure.loginWithUsernamePassword(`${email}@<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com`, `${password}`, { tokenAudience: 'graph', domain: tenantId }, function (err, credentials, subscriptions) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(credentials.tokenCache)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: few days ago, they announced the preview feature for iframe compatibility (i.e. embedded login):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/embedded-login?pivots=b2c-custom-policy
of course, it's better if you don't use it in production yet, but it might be the solution you were looking for. :)

**Old answer:**

The only way to achieve that is by using ROPC, as you mentioned. ROPC is insecure basically because for some time you have to manage the credentials of the user (unlike when the user directly inserts them in B2C), but in your case, this is a requirement.

You cannot achieve this with Graph API, because you'll be only able to register the user, update his/her data (incl. password), but you won't be able to get an access token.